# Resque web interface loading error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I have installed Resque in Rails 3 using [this tutorial](http://blog.redistogo.com/2010/07/26/resque-with-redis-to-go/).

The problem is when I'm trying to use the Resque web interface. When I go to `{localhost}/resque/` , the browser is getting redirected to `{localhost}/resque/resque/overview/true/false` which essentially does not exist. 
However `{localhost}/resque/overview` seems to open up the correct interface, although has broken links. (Like clicking on stats again redirects me to `{localhost}/resque/resque/stats/resque/true/false`, which is again non-existant)

Here is my config.ru file:

```
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)

require 'resque/server'
require 'logger'

# Set the AUTH env variable to your basic auth password to protect Resque.
AUTH_PASSWORD = 'secret'
if AUTH_PASSWORD
  Resque::Server.use Rack::Auth::Basic do |username, password|
    password == AUTH_PASSWORD 
  end
end

run Rack::URLMap.new \
  "/"       => Marina::Application,
  "/resque" => Resque::Server.new
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that it's a problem with Sinatra version 1.2.0. Using Sinatra 1.1.3 works fine. Details on this Resque open issue: https://github.com/defunkt/resque/issues#issue/221

From the issue description:

> When I go to "/resque" route it
>   redirects to
>   "/resque/resque/overview/true/false"
>   and fail with 404 Sinatra error page.
>
> Add sinatra 1.1.3 to Gemfile, run
>   "bundle update sinatra" and voila:
>   http://cl.ly/460d0C0x2N1W2D333j1f

As I'm new to Ruby and don't know yet what is a Gemfile :), I forced the installation of Sinatra 1.1.3 and it worked like a charm:

```
$ gem uninstall sinatra
$ gem install sinatra -v 1.1.3
```

Regards,
Deluan.